# Потокобезопасность перегруженного new/delete

Tags: c++, указатели, память, delete, new

знаю, что по стандарту new/delete потобезопасны. Но является ли перегруженные операторы потокобезопасными без лишних телодвижений(захватов mutex и тд).
Так, например, стандартные new/delete вызывают конструкторы/деструкторы, но и перегруженные new/delete вызывают конструкторы/деструкторы без явного указания этого в коде(без pointer->A(), pointer->~A()).
Функции перегружены глобально

Answer (score 1):

Нашел связанный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739144/thread-safety-for-overloaded-operator-new

Краткий перевод.

Для встроенного оператора new стандарт гарантирует, что он будет thread safe (если бы это было не так, сколько бы всего сломалось...).

Для пользовательских операторов это *не гарантируется*, если Вы добавите код, который не есть thread safe, то все будет плохо.

Например, вот такой оператор

```
struct Foo
{
  static void * operator new(size_t n) { return ::operator new(n); } // OK
};
```

это нормально.

А если там начать делать что то свое...